# Does this integral have a special name?

Tags: integration

In my textbook, I came across the following identity:

$$\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z-m)^T A (z-m)} dz = (2\pi)^{\frac{k}{2}} |A|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Where:

- $m$ is a $k$ x $1$ vector
- $A$ is a $m$ x $m$ positive definite matrix

**My Question:** Can someone please show me why this integral is true (i.e. how to solve and get the answer)? Does the integral have a special name (e.g. some special identity)?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically people call this a ($m$-dimensional) Gaussian integral.

Comment: To solve it, you want to diagonalize the matrix $A$ unitarily and then reduce the integral to a product of standard ($1$-dimensional) Gaussian integrals.

Comment: @Severin Schraven: thank you for your reply! When I look at the corresponding Wikipedia page  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral, it appears slightly different?

Comment: Namely, if $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $U$ is a unitary matrix such that $U^* A U = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k)$, then we get $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (z-m)^T A (z-m) \right) dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} x^T A x \right) dx $$ after the change of variables $x=z-m$. Rewrite it as $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (Ux)^T \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) (Ux) \right) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} y^T \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) y \right) dy.  $$

Comment: @Severin Schraven: thank you for your reply!  If you have time, can you please show me how to solve this integral in the answer? thank you so much!

Comment: I guess your matrix is supposed to be $k\times k$, right? Otherwise we cannot take the product with $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People typically call this a ($k$-dimensional) Gaussian integral. Let me briefly show how that formula is derived.

Let's assume that $A$ is Hermitian (this is typically included in the definition of positive-definite matrices, but not all people follow this convention). Then it is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix.

Namely, if $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $U$ is a unitary matrix such that $U^* A U = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k)$, then we get $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (z-m)^T A (z-m) \right) dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} x^T A x \right) dx $$ after the change of variables $x=z-m$. Rewrite it as
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (Ux)^T \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) (Ux) \right) dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} y^T \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) y \right) dy \\ &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j y_j^2 \right) dy,
\end{align*}
where we used the change of variables $y=Ux$. Now use the specific structure to write it as
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \prod_{j=1}^k \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_j y_j^2\right) dy = \prod_{j=1}^k \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda_j y_j^2} dy_j
= \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_j}} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-\frac{1}{2}s_j^2} ds_j = \frac{(2\pi)^{k/2}}{\sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^k \lambda_j}}, $$
where we used the standard ($1$-dimensional) Gaussian integral. Now conclude using the fact that
$$ \prod_{j=1}^k \lambda_j = \det(A). $$

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I had a question about your answer - i posted it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785333/simplifications-of-hermitian-matrices .... can you please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob I have just used that $x^T U^T=(Ux)^T$.

Comment: @ Severin Schraven: Do you have any ideas about this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787116/finding-the-name-of-this-algebra-identity

Comment: @stats_noob Unfortunately, I don't :(

Answer (score 1):

The motivation of this is when you have a vector $Z = (Z_1, \dots, Z_k)$, where $Z_1, \dots, Z_k$ are i.i.d. $N(0, 1)$ and an $k \times k$ invertible matrix $B$ and you form the random vector $X = BZ$. Such a vector $X$ is said to have a multivariate normal distribution. You want to find the density of $X$. Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}^k$. Then
\begin{align}
P(X \in S) &= P(Z \in B^{-1}S) \\
&= \int_{B^{-1}S}(2\pi)^{-k/2}\exp(-|z|^2/2)\,dz.
\end{align}
Now make the substitution $x = Bz$, $dx = |B|\,dz$ to get
\begin{align}
P(X \in S) &= \int_{S}(2\pi)^{-k/2}\exp(-|B^{-1}x|^2/2)\,\frac{1}{|B|}dx \\
&= (2\pi)^{-k/2}|B|^{-1}\int_{S}\exp(-x^T(BB^T)^{-1}x/2)\,dx.
\end{align}
Hence the density of $X$ is
$$f_X(x) = (2\pi)^{-k/2}|B|^{-1}\exp(-x^T(BB^T)^{-1}x/2).$$
Now let $A = (BB^T)^{-1}$ (every positive definite matrix $A$ can be written in this form, e.g. by diagonalizing). Since $|A| = \frac{1}{|B|^2}$,
$$f_X(x) = (2\pi)^{-k/2}|A|^{1/2}\exp(-x^T A x/2).$$
The result now follows from the fact that $1 = P(X \in \mathbb{R}^k) = \int f_X(x)\,dx$.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!