# Simplifications of Hermitian Matrices

Tags: integration

Recently, I posted the following question [Does this integral have a special name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785293/does-this-integral-have-a-special-name) on understand this integral:

$$\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z-m)^T A (z-m)} dz = (2\pi)^{\frac{k}{2}} |A|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Where:

- $m$ is a $k$ x $1$ vector
- $A$ is a $m$ x $m$ positive definite matrix

The following answer was then provided (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4785301/791334):

**People typically call this a** ($k$-dimensional) **Gaussian integral. Let me briefly show how that formula is derived.**

**Let's assume that** $A$ i**s Hermitian (this is typically included in the definition of positive-definite matrices, but not all people follow this convention). Then it is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix.**

**Namely, if** $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ **are the eigenvalues of** $A$ **and** $U$ **is a unitary matrix such that** $U^* A U = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k)$, **then we get** $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (z-m)^T A (z-m) \right) dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} x^T A x \right) dx $$ **after the change of variables** $x=z-m$. **Rewrite it as**
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (Ux)^T \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) (Ux) \right) dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} y^T \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) y \right) dy \\ &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j y_j^2 \right) dy,
\end{align*}

I have the following question: How do we go from

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} x^T A x \right) dx $$  to

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (z-m)^T A (z-m) \right) dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} (Ux)^T \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k) (Ux) \right) dx  $$

Can someone please explain this logic?

Thanks!

Comment: $A=U\Lambda U^T$ (diagonal matrix $\Lambda$) so the result should follow directly. We also have $|A|=|\Lambda|$.